# Can a call for developers be a valid question?

Tags: support, scope

Could I make a call for a free software project on Stack Overflow? I guess it would be something like asking for 'help' with something concerning software :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be sneaky. Stackoverflow is about code, and so you should start coding and present an issue you stumble upon as question. That's not only legitimate but also an opportunity to link to your project. If it's interesting enough, people will ask/join automatically. If it's too boring, then any effort to advertise it or broadly ask for help would be pointless.

Comment: +1 for "be sneaky" :D In other words, "when working on your project, use SO for its intended purpose"

Comment: Pretty fair : D

Answer (score 10):

No, I'm afraid that would be outside the scope of the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).  However, if you start an Open Source project you can participate in the [Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/) program to try and attract other developers to your project.